# Python--Two iterative loops not spitting out all correct answers

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code. It's supposed to list the combinations of boxes of nuggets (6,9, 20 piece) for a number of nuggets.  However, some of the solutions are not being calculated.

```
def boxes_nuggets(nuggets):

    if nuggets < 6: print "there are no sizes for less than 6 nuggets"
    else:
        for numSmall in range(0, nuggets/6+1):
            for numMed in range(0, nuggets/9+1):
                numLarge = (nuggets - 6 * numSmall - 9 * numMed)/20
                if nuggets == numLarge * 20 + numMed * 9 + numSmall * 6:
                    print numLarge, "large boxes", numMed, "medium boxes", numSmall, "small boxes"

                elif numLarge < 0: return None
```

Comment: Either (a) provide runnable code, or (b) at least tell us which values caused your code to fail. We don't want to have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change your code to this:

```
if numLarge < 0:
    continue
if nuggets == numLarge * 20 + numMed * 9 + numSmall * 6:
    print ...
```

So, remove the `elif numLarge < 0: return None` and add the check for negative numLarge before printing.

The problem you were having is the first time numLarge goes negative, you return, which stops the rest of the possible answers from being found.

```
def boxes_nuggets(nuggets):
    if nuggets < 6: print "there are no sizes for less than 6 nuggets"
    else:
        for numSmall in range(nuggets/6+1):
            for numMed in range(nuggets/9+1):
                numLarge = (nuggets - 6 * numSmall - 9 * numMed)/20
                if numLarge < 0: continue
                if nuggets == numLarge * 20 + numMed * 9 + numSmall * 6:
                    print numLarge, "large boxes", numMed, "medium boxes", numSmall, "small boxes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Good use of nested loops to calculate the possible combinations. Just replace the return statement with a continue statement to remove the error. Rest looks fine to me.